# Para que serve " .= " no PHP e quando usar?

Tags: php

Bom galera estou com uma duvida estava analisando um código em php e vi que em um `foreach` é usado a expressão `$main .= '...';` e gostaria de saber para que serve e quando usar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenação de string

O mesmo que:

```
$main = $main . '...';
```

Ex:

```
$main = 'teste';
$main .= '1';
$main .= '2';
$main .= '3';

echo $main; //irá imprimir 'teste123'
```